# Translating a regex into a more basic code

Tags: java, regex

How can I write the below code without using regex?

```
public static boolean validateCode(String code){
    boolean hasAtLeastOneNumber = Pattern.compile("[0-9].*[0-9]")
                                         .matcher(code).find();

    boolean hasAtLeastTwoLetters = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]")
                                          .matcher(code).find();

    boolean hasAtLeastOneHyphen = Pattern.compile("-")
                                         .matcher(code).find();
}
```

Comment: when you say "classic" code, what mechanisms of String are you willing to restrict yourself to? Are you allowed to use `contains` and/or `startsWith` or are you literally trying to parse the characters entirely in home baked methods?

Comment: im new student, im  literally trying to parse the characters entirely in home baked methods, thats the only thing left i have to do to finish my homeexam, i just dont know how

Comment: oh, then disregard my answer... I'll edit it

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet. You need to show some effort in order to get answers. We're not here to complete your assignments for you.

Comment: i was thinking about making 3 variables, 2 ints and 1 boolean but my teacher said it wouldnt be a good way to do it..

Comment: By the way, `Pattern.compile(something).matcher(code).find()` can be replaced with `code.matches(something)`.

Comment: Can you post the code that you were going to use to solve the issue

Comment: Why? What benefit are you expecting to get by hand-coding a compact and apparently working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
public static boolean validateCode2(String code) {
    int numbers = 0, letters = 0, hyphens = 0;
    for (char c : code.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) numbers++;
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) letters++;
        if (c=='-') hyphens++;
    }

    return numbers>=2 && letters>=2 && hyphens>=1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For `hasAtLeastOneNumber`:

```
for (char c : code.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        return true;
    }
return false;
```

For `hasAtLeastTwoLetters`:

```
int numFound = 0;
for (char c : code.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        numFound++;
        if (numFound >= 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

For `hasAtLeastOneHyphen`:

```
for (char c : code.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '-') {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

---

If you don't want to use `toCharArray`, you could use:

```
for (int i=0; i<code.length(); i++) {
    char c = code.charAt(i);
    // do the rest of the test here
}
```

That's basically equivalent to using `toCharArray` except that it's slightly more confusing: someone who looks at the code would need to take a second or two to figure it out. With `toCharArray` it's obvious what you're doing.

Comment: What *can* you use? You could wrap this in `charAt` calls, but that's kind of silly.

Comment: what do u mean wrap it in charAt, ive learned charAt but i havent learned arrays

Comment: Also, keep in mind that toCharArray is typically faster if `code`/`codego` is more than 64 characters long.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand why 64? Looking at the `java.lang.String` source, `toCharArray` just uses `System.arraycopy`, while `charAt` just uses subscript notation. Is it the method call that's expensive?

Comment: i dont use toCharArray becouse ive learned it yet, not becouse of how fast it is

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the string and test it for ranges of characters.  See an example on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/MXryfv), or ask me if you need an explanation.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(validarCodigo("No-numbers"));
        System.out.println(validarCodigo("1-A"));
        System.out.println(validarCodigo("This 1 Matches -- :-)"));
    }

    public static boolean validarCodigo(String codigo) {
        int i;
        char[] chars = codigo.toCharArray();
        char current;
        boolean tieneAlmenosUnNumero = false;
        boolean tieneAlmenosDosLetras = false;
        boolean tieneAlmenosUnGuion = false;

        // Check for at least one number
        for (i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            current = chars[i];
            if (current >= '0' && current <= '9') {
                tieneAlmenosUnNumero = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Check for at least two letters
        int found = 0;
        for (i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            current = chars[i];
            boolean lower = current >= 'a' && current <= 'z';
            boolean upper = current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z';

            if (lower || upper) found++;

            if (found == 2){
                tieneAlmenosDosLetras = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Check for at least one hyphen
        for (i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            current = chars[i];
            if (current == '-') {
                tieneAlmenosUnGuion = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        return tieneAlmenosUnNumero && tieneAlmenosDosLetras && tieneAlmenosUnGuion;
    }
}
```